# how to return value from this async function? img.onLoad event

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, return, onload, onload-event

How do I return `height` from function `getImgSize(imgSrc)`? Bear in mind that `onload()` is async.

```js
function getImgSize(imgSrc) {
  const img = new Image();

  img.onload = function() {
    const height = img.height;
  }
  img.src = url;
}
```

Comment: You can't return anything from an event handler. What's the actual issue you're attempting to solve here?

Comment: i fetch 20 pics. I want to sort them from the smallest one to the biggest one. When it is sorted, i want to display it.

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap it in a [promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) (called ["promisification"](https://javascript.info/promisify)):

```js
function getImgSize(imgSrc){
  const img = new Image();

  img.src = imgSrc;

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    img.onload = function() {
      const height = img.height; 

      resolve(height); // Promise resolves to this value
    };

    img.onerror = function(error) {
      reject(error); // Promise rejects with the error
    };
  });
}
```

But then you can only call this function in an async context. Most modern browsers support top-level await (in scripts where type=module), but just in case, you may want to wrap it in a function:

```js
(async () => {
  const heightOfImage = await getImgSize("...");
})();
```